# show div when clicked on image using cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have got a map with markers as below.  I want to show the div "popup" close to the particular img I clicked on (cursor position). The markers are loaded by an ajax call.

JQuery (JS):

```
$( "img").on('click', function(event) {
  var div = $("#popup");
  div.css( {
      display:"absolute",
      top:event.pageY, 
      left: event.pageX});


  return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
<img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; left: 483px; top: -188px;" src="http://a.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/10/540/357.png"></img>

<img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; left: 739px; top: -188px;" src="http://b.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/10/541/357.png"></img>

<img class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; left: 227px; top: 68px;" src="http://a.tile.cloudmade.com/BC9A493B41014CAABB98F0471D759707/997/256/10/539/358.png">
</img>
<div id="popup">showme</div>
```

Comment: can you please add a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you just used the CSS property "display" instead of "position" in your JS.

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T32ZV/

And here's the working code:

```
$( "img").on('click', function(event) {
    var div = $("#popup");
    div.css({
       position:"absolute",
       top:event.pageY, 
       left: event.pageX
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: yes, it is working but not showing on the right position. In my app I use webcam images as a marker. I was mistaken by the marker imgs I posted (these were map panes). What element (webcam) do i need to click to show the popup ? See: http://skiweather.eu/gmap9/

Comment: The "click" event wasn't called on your website - it propably was canceled by another event attached to the imgs. However, if you use the 'mousedown' event instead of 'click' in your jQuery(".xyz").on(..) i will get called.

Answer (score 1):

hide the $('#popup') first and your css property was wrong, `position` instead of `display`

```
<div id="popup" style="display:none">showme</div>

$("img").on('click', function(event) {
  var div = $("#popup");
    div.css( {
      position:"absolute",
      top:event.pageY, 
      left: event.pageX
      }).show();

  return false;
});
```